# JavaScript: Why do we use **arguments** object in a function?

Tags: javascript

I noticed that in some functions the arguments object is used:

```
function fn(arg1, arg2)
{
    console.log(arguments[0])
}

fn(1, 2); // 1
```

Why it is useful?

Comment: we can use it for unknown parameter so...

Comment: The `arguments` object is kind of special, but it's most commonly used for a variable number of args. There are useful properties like `caller` and `callee` as well. More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Answer (score 2):

In your example, it's not useful and not a good idea. It can be useful when you want a function that can accept an indefinite number of arguments:

```
function sum() {
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i += 1) {
        total += arguments[i];
    }
    return total;
}

console.log(sum(5, 6, 7, 8));   // 26
```

Note that ES6 allows the use of [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) which would be more useful in most cases where `arguments` are used nowadays:

```
function sum(...values) {
    return values.reduce(function (prev, cur) {
        return prev + cur;
    }, 0);
}
```